# Hot Chocolate Graphql Stitching - How to route the query / mutation based on variable value

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

We would like to route the queries / mutation to different endpoints with the same schema. I'm not sure if stitching is the way to go. But is someone can advise.

Traffic will be routed through an Azure Api Manager, to the GraphQL Stitched Gateway, to the respective Endpoint depending on a variable value, which is an C# Enum, sample options would be Country1 or Country2.

Below is the sample variable json. Region is the determining variable.

```
{  
  "region": "Country1",
  "date": "2022-10-18",  
  "storeId": "GB123456",
  "externalServiceId": "FHA"
}
```

Any advise much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using Azure Api Manager Policy to reroute the traffic to the correct GraphQL Application service.

Using "check-header" on Inbound requests.